# How to use AI for language recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, audio-processing, speech-recognition

Given an audio track, I'm trying to find a way to recognize the audio language. Only within a small set (e.g. English vs Spanish). Is there a simple solution to detect the language in a speech?

Comment: If you are finding a tool, this question maybe off topic. @nbro

Comment: No tool. A simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Google has an API you can use. https://cloud.google.com/translate/. Their API can translate audio to text. They also have an API for converting speech to text. The language detection feature should let you detect the language in the resulting text. They have client libraries for the most popular programming languages.

Comment: Yeah that I know. But then the problem of language detection still remains.

Comment: Google translate can detect the langauge for you as well

Comment: You can see a python example of this at https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/

Comment: Umm good. But something possibly non cloud.